# conversion of php/asp ajax example to jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp

Hi I am new to JSP and i am trying to convert the Ajax example of W3School into jsp but i am not able to do so. Can any one please help.

Here is the PHP example

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Here is the ASP example

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_asp.asp

I have tried with the substring function of java but failed to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those examples can directly run in JSP only by changing the URL and the query-string parameter(s), if any in the `xmlhttp.open(...)` method. Did you try them out?

Comment: i am looking to get the following code in jsp
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";


if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to convert the PHP/ASP code to jsp. Here is the jsp code. Please save this code in gethint.jsp page and in the html page change the URL to target the jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
<%
// Array with names
String hint = " "; 
String[] a = {
    "Anna","Brittany","Cinderella","Diana","Eva","Fiona","Gunda",
    "Hege","Inga","Johanna","Kitty","Linda","Nina","Ophelia"
    ,"Petunia","Amanda","Raquel","Cindy","Doris","Eve","Evita","Sunniva"
   ,"Tove","Unni","Violet","Liza","Elizabeth","Ellen","Wenche","Vicky"
   };
   // get the q parameter from URL
   String q = request.getParameter("q");

   if (q != " ") {
   for(String name : a )
   {
     if(name.toLowerCase().startsWith(q.toLowerCase()))
     {
        if(hint == " ")
        {
           hint = name;
        }
        else
        {
            hint = hint + ", " + name;
        }
    }
  }
 }

 if(hint == " ")
 {
   out.println("No suggestion");    
 }
 else{
 out.println(hint);
  }

  %>
```